# Retag: snowleopardserver => snow-leopard-server

Tags: support, retag-request

Serverfault Retag Request:

`snowleopardserver` x6 to `snow-leopard-server` x13

The latter is already favored by the community and is correctly formatted.

Answer (score 4):

Might as well do `snowleopard` > `snow-leopard` while you are at it.

Also, there are two anomalous `snow` `leopard`-tagged questions that need to have those tags fixed into a single tag: `snow-leopard`.

For such a small number of re-tags, I'd just do it myself but I don't have the rep on that system to do the editing.

Comment: I was bored ... so i did it